# $1!+2!+\ldots+n!$ cannot be the square of a positive integer

Tags: induction, factorial

I have to prove that $1!+2!+\ldots+n!$ cannot be the square of a positive
integer, $\forall n\geq4$.

I've tried to do this with induction, but I don't seem to reach any satisfactory conclusion.

Any hint will do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:  First, see if you can show that no perfect square can be equivalent to $3 \pmod{10}$.

From here, note that $n! \equiv 0 \pmod{10}$ for all $n \geq 5$.

Hence, we get:

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk! \equiv 1! + 2! + 3! + 4! \equiv 33 \equiv 3 \pmod{10}$$

Comment: Less than a second difference between our answers :)

Comment: Thank you all for the quick response. I think in the $2^{nd}$ line you meant
$$n!\equiv 0 \pmod{10}\ \ \ \forall n\geq5.$$

Comment: I certainly did!  Thanks for catching that.  If you're good to go, don't forget to accept the answer (click the check-mark) so it no longer shows up as unanswered for other users. :)

Answer (score 4):

See that 1 ! + 2 ! + 3 ! + 4 !=33. And from 5! onwards all the other numbers will end with 0 as its last digit. 
So when you take the sum upto n! with n greater than equal to 4 you can see that the last digit of the sum will be 3. 
So there is no postive integer whose square ends up with 3 as the last digit or unit place's digit. So the sum cannot be a square of a positive integer.

Comment: This is an interesting way of thinking this :) ... thanks

Comment: i did it before u kaj hansen....you should thank me....

Comment: this are easy sums...very very easy....

Answer (score 0):

The square of an integer is always congruent to $0,1\pmod 4$.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, I think this is problematic because the sum is still equivalent to $1 \pmod{4}$.

Comment: An aside: if it can be shown that $9$ is the unique square that is equivalent to $1 \pmod 4$ and $0 \pmod 3$, then this approach can be recovered. I don't know that this is true though; CRT says that any $n$ such that $n \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $n \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ satisfies $n \equiv 9 \pmod {12}$, but that was as far as I was able to go.